# Python Setup on NameCheap showing Error 503. Service Unavailable

Tags: python, django, cpanel, namecheap

I am new to NameCheap and I need help deploying a Django application. I just tried installing python on Namecheap's Cpanel using Python 3.7.12 with the desired Application URL, but I get the Error 503. Service Unavailable when I visit the Application URL after creating the python app. From the resources I have seen, I am supposed to get a python signification that the python app works and not an error. Thanks in advance.
[python app setup on Namecheap's Cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjWS7.png)
[error page when i visit the application's Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJEh.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, Why does it appear?

The Webserver is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.

Also among reasons can be:

inodes/disk overusage

irrelevant php.ini/htaccess directives

incorrect PHP version used

lack of memory

Solution:

1. Switch PHP versions;
2. Check disk space and inodes usage, etc.;
3. Check error logs and the latest error messages to find which script, plugin, etc. causes the issue;
4. ensure the server is up and running.